# Create a font from existing SVG icons

Tags: command-line, icons, fonts

I have a folder of SVG icons which I want to compile into a font. Each icon should be assigned to a unicode character of my choice (eg. `U+F000`). Traditional font editors like Birdfont are really not what I want here, because they require the user to manually edit every single character.

Optimally I would like to have a tool where I can just add a character to my font from the command line like `magictool add --character f000 --file myfile.svg` and then export to ttf or otf. Is there a tool which can do something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import svg files on the command line with the program birdfont-import:

A drawing saved as "a.svg" will be added to the glyph "a" when you run:

```
birdfont-import typeface.bf a.svg
```

A drawing saved as "U+62.svg" will be added to "b" when you run:

```
birdfont-import typeface.bf U+62.svg
```

You can import several files at once (on the command line) with wildcards:

```
birdfont-import typeface.bf *.svg
```

The proprietary version also has a pretty good batch import in the GUI.
It looks like this:
[image: birdfont folder import]

Here are the details:
https://birdfont.org/doku/doku.php/import_multiple_svg_files

There is also a function in the proprietary version that makes it possible to center all glyphs vertically and horizontally with these buttons:

[image: center glyphs]